# Writing a repeating sequence as a function

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following sequence of numbers that I need to express as a piecewise function split into two parts (or two functions).

term index $(j):  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,   6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,\ldots$
$f(j): 15,25,32,38,45,55,| 45,40,40,45,55,45,40,40,45,55,\ldots$

I have an expression already that will give the first $6$ terms above (from $j = 0$ to $j = 5$). Now I'm working on expressing the second set in the sequence (starting from $j = 6$) which will be dependent on the last two terms from the first set (i.e. the terms $45$ and $55$ at $j = 4$ and $j = 5$, respectively).

For example, I'm searching for a function that will give the values $f(j)$ for $j \ge 6$.

I'd appreciate any help/advice on how to proceed with writing this repeating sequence as some sort of a function. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any more information where this sequence comes from? What is the expression for the first 6 terms, that you have figured out? As it stands, there's an infinite number of functions, that satisfy your constraints. (Also, I think you have a typo: $12, 13, 15, 15$ should probably be $12, 13, 14, 15$)

Comment: Consider $\;\ f(n \operatorname{mod} 5)$ with $\;\displaystyle  f(n):=\frac 52(n^2-5 n+22)\;$ for the second part (starting at $j=5$ for $f(5)=55$ with $\operatorname{mod}$ replaced by '%').

Comment: What do you mean by "some sort of a function."? How will you use this "function"? Will you use it in a computer program?

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many continuous functions that satisfy your constraints.
I'm not sure what you want but one good way to express periodicity is to use the roots of unity.
Let $m$ be a positive integer ($m:=5$ in your case).
Let $\omega:=e^{2\pi i/m}$, which is a primitive $m$th root of unity.
Obviously $\omega^n=\omega^{n\text{ mod } m}$.
Suppose we want $f(n)=\alpha_k$ whenever $n\equiv k\text{ (mod }m)$.
Then we can simply use the Lagrange interpolation with nodes $\omega^k$:
$$
f(n):=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \alpha_k \prod_{j=0;j\neq k}^{m-1} \frac{\omega^n-\omega^j}{\omega^k-\omega^j}.
$$
We can simplify this and get
$$
f(n)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \alpha_k \omega^{k}\prod_{j=0;j\neq k}^{m-1} \omega^n-\omega^j.
$$

---

I would like to add some motivation behind this approach, as requested by OP in the comment.
We want to find an expression for the sequence:
$$\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_{m-1},\alpha_0\cdots$$
While we do not know how to directly do this, we do know a convenient expression for the following sequence:
$$1,\omega,\omega^2,\cdots,\omega^{m-1},1,\cdots$$
which is simply $g(n)=\omega^n$.
It remains to find another interesting expression to map each $\omega^k$ to $\alpha_k$.
One way to do this is Lagrange interpolation,
which is a way to find a polynomial $h$ of degree $m-1$ such that
$h(x_k)=y_k$ for all $0\le k < m$,
for some $x_k,y_k$ we can choose arbitrarily (as long as all $x_k$ are distinct).
Explicitly, $h$ is defined as follows:
$$
h(x):=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} y_k \prod_{j=0;j\neq k}^{m-1} \frac{x-x_j}{x_k-x_j}.
$$
In this case, we choose $x_k:=\omega^k$ and $y_k:=\alpha_k$,
and we have
$$
h(x):=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \alpha_k \prod_{j=0;j\neq k}^{m-1} \frac{x-\omega^j}{\omega^k-\omega^j}.
$$
Finally we simply compose $g$ and $h$ to obtain $f:=h\circ g$, i.e.
$$
f(n):=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \alpha_k \prod_{j=0;j\neq k}^{m-1} \frac{\omega^n-\omega^j}{\omega^k-\omega^j}
$$
as in my original answer.

---

By the way, you can also choose $h$ (with some offset) to be
$$
h(x):=\frac{5}{2}(x^2-5x+22),
$$
as given by @Raymond Manzoni in the comment.
The reason why a quadratic polynomial also works is that
the repeating elements of your sequence have a common difference.

Comment: Thank you, this was a big help! I was curious about the reason for using the primitive roots of unity in the interpolation formula? Is that for getting the repeated sequence without have to regenerate the Lagrange formula for roots greater than m?

Comment: @Shelly I added some more explanation in my answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that a "not-too-messy" closed form exists for $f(j)$; nevertheless, a tool that might help to circumvent your problem is the generating function $-$ [here](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfology2.pdf) is a great book about it.

In your case, as the first four terms are irregular before the sequence becomes 5-periodic, it would work as follows :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
F(x) &=& \displaystyle
     \sum_{j=0}^\infty f(j)x^j \\
     &=& \displaystyle
     15 + 25x + 32x^2 + 38x^3 + x^4\left(45\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{5n} + 50\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{5n+1} + 45\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{5n+2} + 40\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{5n+3} + 40\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{5n+4}\right) \\
    &=& \displaystyle
    15 + 25x + 32x^2 + 38x^3 + \frac{x^4}{1-x^5}\left(45 + 50x + 45x^2 + 40x^3 + 40x^4\right)
\end{array}
$$
Now $f(j)$ is implicitly defined through the generating function $F(x)$ in the following way : $f(j) := \frac{F^{(j)}(0)}{j!}$, where $F^{(j)}$ is the $j^{\mathrm{th}}$ derivative of $F$.

You could also use an exponential generating function, defined as $\tilde{F}(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty f(j)\frac{x^j}{j!}$, which will be often easier to differentiate, such that $f(j) := \tilde{F}^{(j)}(0)$.